# Why won't keyup() and keydown() play nicely together?

Tags: jquery

I can't get  the jQuery `keyup` and `keydown` events to work together. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CXkam/1/

Code here too for ease:

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    alert('Keyup');
});
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    alert('Keypress: ' + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    alert('Keydown: ' + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

If you comment out the `keypress()` and `keydown()` handlers, then the `keyup()` alert fires.

But if you don't, then `keyup()` never fires.

Why not?

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/CXkam/2/

Comment: thanks for the answers everyone. should i report this as a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .keyup and .keypress events won't fire if you release the key while the dialogue box is up because the keyup message is sent to the dialogue box, which, for reasons beyond my very limited understanding of things, is not considered part of the document.  What you *can* do, if you want to see it "work," is hold a key down (let's go with *T*!), hit spacebar to dismiss the dialogue box, and then release the *T* key.  The .keyup message will then be sent to the document and processed as intended.

If you get rid of the .keydown and .keypress functions -- or the alerts within them -- then .keyup will work just fine.

Comment: I suppose not.  However, the point still stands that it's being broken by the alerts.  Apparently in IE, in a slightly different manner -- they interrupt the key and force an immediate key press/up event.

Comment: Agree on that. Definitely alert is the evil here. Interesting :)

Answer (score 5):

hmm, I think it's actually to do with a problem with alert(). Maybe it's being called too fast or something. Because if you replace it with console.log calls, you can clearly see it's working

http://jsfiddle.net/WJsV6/ Try it in FF. All 3 methods actually fire

Comment: @Reigel Yup, that's better. Try the above link to witness the weirdness!